# Help solving an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following equation:
$$x'+\frac{2}{t}x=-t^9x^5 \tag{1}$$

I ave recognised that this is a Bernoulli's equation, hence I have done the substitution $z=x^{1-5}=x^{-4}$, however I reach a point where I have the following:

$$
4z'+\frac{2}{t}z+t^9z^{17}=0 \tag{2}
$$

where I have assumed that $x(t)>0$ and so $z(t)>0$. I'm stuck at how to solve $(2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your equation in the form
$$\frac{-4x'(t)}{x(t)^5}-\frac{8}{tx(t)^4}=-4t^9$$ now we substitute
$$v(t)=\frac{1}{x(t)^4}$$ so we get $$v'(t)-\frac{8v(t)}{t}=4t^9$$ computing $$\mu(t)=e^{-\int\frac{8}{t}dt}=\frac{1}{t^8}$$ and we get
$$\frac{v'(t)}{t^8}-\frac{8v(t)}{t^9}=4t$$ and we get
$$\int\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{v(t)}{t^8}\right)dt=\int4tdt$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Yeah, getting to that substitution was the key. So simple... Thank you